# Logical operation on Pandas dataframe made from pyspark object is causing a kernel to start and restart randomly

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, distributed-computing

I appologize in advance but I am not allowed to share the data I am working with so I cannot really share my code and I am unsure of how to make a reproducible example for this case at all as the data is so large its not easy to share anyway.  Some of my problems may be down to hardware as I am working on an 8 core machine with pyspark and I think there is som LazyEvaluation taking place since I had to pull data into pandas to avoid index size errors.  When I was working with the pyspark.pandas.dataframe object it would load with different row numbers and the boolean mask I was tryingt o create would also have different lengths when I made it so when I went to do the indexing it would fail.  My solution was just to load a summary of the data into a normal pandas dataframe.

With that caveat basically, I am working with data in pyspark, I converted data from a pyspark object to a pyspark.pandas.dataframe then converted that into a real dataframe which is this output here:

```
client_counts_df = billing_aggs_df.groupby('client_group').agg({'client_group': 'count', 'SALES_VALUE_USD': 'sum'})
client_counts_df.columns = ['Count', 'Total_Sales_USD']
client_counts_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
client_counts_df = client_counts_df.dropna()
client_counts_df = client_counts_df.to_pandas()
```

Now here I work do some logial operations, I have the print statements to verify what is happening.

```
countries = np.unique(billing_aggs_df.COUNTRY_CODE.to_numpy())
country = countries[0]
print(country)
print(client_counts_df.shape)
this_country_sales_idx = client_counts_df['client_group'].astype(str).str.contains('sales', case=False)
print(len(this_country_sales_idx))
this_country_sales_idx[0:5]
```

The cell in my jupyternotebook execute fine but will randomly start executing again and outputting this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda/envs/examplecompany/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/daemon.py", line 193, in manager
...
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

The error is a non issue in the sense that it does not interrupt the notebook from operating normally and the cell executed fine, but its curious to see every couple of fractions of a second the cell start executing code again and then returns that error.  It stops after a couple of minutes but it is bizarre.

What is causing this?  Any guesses?